# how to make a popup page using bootstrap modal in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple rails app where a user can add a product and as the user clicks on the f.submit button it takes them to show.html.erb but what I want to do now is to make the `show.html.erb` a popup, as am new to rails I don't have any idea on how to accomplish this.

What I tried is bootstrap modal

**my show.html.erb**

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="load-<%= load.id %>-notes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="load-<%= load.id %>-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="load-<%= load.id %>-label">Notes</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>
  <strong>Pickup:</strong>
  <%= @load.pickup %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Delivery:</strong>
  <%= @load.delivery %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @load.date %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Truck:</strong>
  <%= @load.truck %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Phone:</strong>
  <%= @load.phone %>
</p>

<strong><font style="text-transform: capitalize;"><%= @load.user.full_name %></strong></font>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**my routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :loads
  resources :reviews
  get 'activities/index'
  get 'profiles/show'
  get 'pages/about'
  get 'pages/contact'
  get 'pages/urgentshipment'
  get 'pages/howitworks'
  get 'pages/review'
  get 'pages/sitemap'
  get 'comments/notification_update'


  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
  resources :shipments do
    member do
      get "like", to: "shipments#upvote"
    end
    resources :comments 
  end
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".
  authenticated :user do
    root 'shipments#index', as: "authenticated_root"
  end
  root "pages#homepage"
  get '/:id', to: 'profiles#show'
  # mailbox folder routes
  get "mailbox/inbox" => "mailbox#inbox", as: :mailbox_inbox
  get "mailbox/sent" => "mailbox#sent", as: :mailbox_sent
  get "mailbox/trash" => "mailbox#trash", as: :mailbox_trash

  # conversations
  resources :conversations do
    member do
      post :reply
      post :trash
      post :untrash
    end
  end
end
```

**my controller**

```
class LoadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_load, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /loads
  # GET /loads.json
  def index
    @loads = Load.all
  end

  # GET /loads/1
  # GET /loads/1.json
  def show
    @load = Load.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /loads/new
  def new
    @load = Load.new
  end

  # GET /loads/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /loads
  # POST /loads.json
  def create
    @load = current_user.loads.new(load_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @load.save
        format.html { redirect_to @load, notice: 'Shipment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @load }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @load.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /loads/1
  # PATCH/PUT /loads/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @load.update(load_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @load, notice: 'Load was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @load }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @load.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /loads/1
  # DELETE /loads/1.json
  def destroy
    @load.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to loads_url, notice: 'Load was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_load
      @load = Load.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def load_params
      params.require(:load).permit(:pickup, :delivery, :date, :truck, :phone, :user_id)
    end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="row vertical-offset-100">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
    <%= simple_form_for @load, html: {class: "well", multipart: true } do |f| %>

    <fieldset>
      <h1 class="text-center login-title"><strong> Hey <%= current_user.first_name %></strong> </h1> 
      <h3 class="text-center login-title"><strong> Let's fill the Shipment Details </strong> </h3>
      <%= f.input :pickup, placeholder: "Where Do You Want The Shipper To Arrive?", label: "Pickup Location" %>
      <%= f.input :delivery, placeholder: "Where Do You Want To Move The Shipment?", label: "Delivery Location" %>
      <%= f.input :date, placeholder: "When Do You Want To Ship?", label: "Date Of Shipment" %>
      <%= f.input :truck, :collection => ["Mini(Tempo)", "Tata Ace(Chota Hathi", "Max(MaxiTruck)","Max+(Tata 407"], placeholder: "Choose Your Vehicle", label: "Trucks", :prompt => 'Select Your Vehicle' %>
      <%= f.input :phone, placeholder: "Your Mobile Number", label: "Contact Number" %>
    <div class="text-center">
<%= link_to 'Add release', load_id:  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'}  %>
  </button>

          </div>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the form code?

Comment: added the form code @Pavan

Comment: Do you want the show.html.erb to be a page that opens a modal once it's loaded, or do you literally want just a modal to open after the user submits the form?

Comment: i want the show.html.erb to be a page that opens a modal once it's loaded. I hope it will be more good. what do you think @JeffF.

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks the f.submit button you should be able to redirect them to any view you'd like (in your case, show.html.erb).  One way to acheieve the pop-up display (without using libraries and such) would be to style that specific show.html.erb page so that it gives the illusion of a pop-up.  Make the actual page-content smaller (giving the semblance of a pop-up window and style it accordingly) and then just set the background of the body to an opacity < 1.

Comment: sorry but am new to rails and programming can you please elaborate @dannyk

Answer (score 0):

In your show.html.erb, add some javascript to show the modal on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#load-<%= load.id %>-notes').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Hopefully, you'll have more stuff on the page because a user can close the modal and they'll be on your show page still.

Comment: it's giving this error
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
@JeffF

Comment: I previously forgot the '#' in the jquery selector. I just edited to add it, try that.

Comment: That error is likely coming from your `<%= load.id %>` that you used in a few spots. Those should be `@load`.

Comment: tried everything but it doesn't seems to work @JeffF

Comment: it doesn't shows any error the load just got saved but there is no popup or redirection to other page